# Signature not getting display on Canvas element in html5

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a signature on Canvas, but the signature is not getting displayed. I need the canvas to fit 100% width and the signature needs to appear without stretching. Here is the code.

Here is my Code :

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile 1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"  />
<div data-role="page">
<div id="divcontent" data-role="content">
<table border='0' width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td style='background-color:blue'>
        <div id="sketch">
        <canvas id="paint"  style='width:100%;height:90px;background-  color:yellow'></canvas>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Js:

```
<script>
  (function() {
var canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
 var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));

var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
var last_mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

/* Mouse Capturing Work */
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
    last_mouse.y = mouse.y;
    //alert("call");
    console.log(mouse.x);
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft-6;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop-356;
    console.log("muse y:"+mouse.y);
}, false);


/* Drawing on Paint App */
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
}, false);

var onPaint = function() {
console.log("paint");
console.log("last_mouse.x"+last_mouse.x);
console.log("last_mouse.y"+last_mouse.y);
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    console.log("paint mouse.x"+mouse.x);
    console.log("paint mouse.y"+mouse.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.stroke();
};

 }());

 </script>
```

How to fix this in order to draw a signature.

Answer (score 0):

First download a touch enabled jquery plugin for drawing on a canvas from

https://github.com/jimdoescode/jqScribble

It work in both desktop browser and mobile devices.

Add following script in your html file

```
<script src="js/jquery.jqscribble.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqscribble.extrabrushes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Signature demo</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/jquery.jqscribble.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/jqscribble.extrabrushes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
</head>
<body>      
  <div data-role="page" id="page_id" >
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">           
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin-top:60px;" >
        <div class="heading">CREATE SIGNATURE HERE</div>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid red;"></canvas>
        <input type="button" data-ajax="false" onclick='save();'  class="ui-btn" value="Accept" />
        <input type="button" data-ajax="false" onclick='$("#canvas").data("jqScribble").clear();'  class="ui-btn" value="Resign" />
    </div>
   </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function save()
{

    $("#canvas").data("jqScribble").save(function(imageData)
    {           
        if(confirm("Are you sure want to save a signature image?"))
        {
            $.post('your_sign.php', {imagedata: imageData}, function(response)
            {
                 alert(imageData)

            });

        }else{
            return;
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#canvas").jqScribble();
    $(document).bind('touchmove', false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ved, can you help me of how to resize this canvas according to the width of screen and the drawn image also needs to be correct without stretching.

Comment: If you using Jquery Mobile then auto resize this canvas according to the width of screen otherwise follow this link http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ and for image stretching read plugin in above posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Filling the canvas with your signature requires several steps:**

1. Capture the users signature strokes in an array of points.
2. Calculate how much to scale your signature.
3. Draw the scaled signature on the canvas.

Here's how to do it:

**Capture the users signature strokes in an array of points.**

- At the app's start, create an empty points[] array: var points=[];
- In mousemove: add each mouse coordinate to the points[] array: points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});

When the user is finished, calculate the bounding box of those points.

You do this by iterating through each point in the points[] array and saving the minimumX, minimumY, maximumX and maximumY.

Then calculate the signature width and height:

```
var sigWidth=maximumX-minumumX;
var sigHeight=maximumY-minumumY;
```

**Calculate how much to scale your signature.**

Now you know the signature size and the canvas size, so you can calculate the scaling factor to apply to both the width and height of your signature.

- Make the signature fill the canvas.
- Scale while maintaining the aspect ratio of the original signature so it doesn't distort.

Calculate the `scaling factor`:

```
function scalePreserveAspectRatio(sigWidth,sigHeight,canvasWidth,canvasHeight){

    return(Math.min((canvasWidth/sigWidth),(canvasHeight/sigHeight)));

}
```

**Draw the scaled signature on the canvas**

```
// left-top justify all the points in the points[] array
for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    points.x-=minimumY;
    points.y-=minumumY
}

// get the scaling factor

var scale=scalePreserveAspectRatio(sigWidth,sigHeight,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// draw the points multiplied by the scaling factor

context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo( points[0].x*scale, points[0].y*scale );
for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    context.lineTo( points[i].x*scale, points[i].y*scale );
}

// stroke the signature

context.stroke();
```

**For a more visually appealing signature**

Apply a line simplifying algorithm to your points[] array (less points==less "jaggies").

Apply a line smoothing algorithm to your points[] array (uses splines to make signature "curvey").